# How to check the JSON response types when using FastAPI testclient

Tags: python, json, python-3.6, fastapi

I'm using the FastAPI testclient to test the response of my API routes. Now I want to determine the types of the JSON response.

For example my response is:

```json
{"userID": 50}
```

I know how to test this hard coded:

```py
assert response.json == {'userID': 50}
```

But my goal is to check only if the response returns the key `userID` or check the type of the key value. For example:

```py
assert response.json == {'userID': int}
```

Ultimately, I am only looking for a way to check whether the desired key names are present.

Comment: For example `assert 'userID' in response.json() and type(response.json()['userID']) is int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any regular Python supported way of checking a type:

```
user_response = response.json()
assert type(user_response['userID']) == int
```

or

```
assert isinstance(user_response['userID'], 3)
```